# Cross-forest GPO between 2003 and 2008 Denied Beacuse it's "Inaccessible"

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, group-policy, active-directory

I have a two-way, non-transitive trust between two forests and domains, "W2003" and "W2008".

In W2008 I have a GPO with user settings linked to a machine OU containing machine "Server".  The GPO applies to Authenticated Users.

Cross-forest loopback processing is enabled in merge mode.

When I log onto Server as User (whose account exists in the W2003 domain), the GPO does not apply.

I run RSoP and see that the GPO is "Denied" for the reason "Inaccessible."  The GPO name is not listed, but the GUID is.

I have checked the file-level permissions on the DC to ensure that User has access to read the GPO's folder and all its contents.

What is going on?

Comment: I found a workaround by copying the policy folder from the DC where the GPO lives to the DC in the domain my user is logging in from.

Comment: So you copied the policy folder from one sysvol to the other domain's sysvol? Did you export/import the GPO in GPMC, or just copy the folder directly?